# Boundedness of Union in Time of Semigroup Acting on a Bounded Set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

I'm studying some introductory material on the $C^0$ semigroup of solution operators S(t). I'm reading through a textbook and in one place, they state that $\bigcup\limits_{0\leq t\leq t_0}S(t) B$ is clearly bounded if $B$ is bounded, and also clearly closed if $B$ is compact. However, I'm not finding this obvious. I think all we need is the continuity of $S$ in both time and with respect to the initial data and the boundedness/closedness of B, but I'm not sure exactly how to flesh out the details. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For reference, this is in Robinson's book (where he is taking closed neighborhoods of an absorbing set $B$) on Infinite-Dimensional Dynamical Systems pg 264 (and yes, I checked the errata as well).

Comment: I think it may actually require $B$ to be compact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Partial answer: boundedness in the case where $\{S(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a semigroup of linear operators.

Since $B$ is bounded, there exists $C>0$ such that
$$\|b\|\leq C,\quad\forall\ b\in B.$$

Take $x\in\bigcup\limits_{0\leq t\leq t_0}S(t) B$. Then there exist $t_x\in[0,t_0]$ and $b_x\in B$ such that
$$x=S(t_x)b_x.$$

From the joint continuity of  $S$ (see equation (10.2) in the said book), there exists a constant $M$ (which depends only on $t_0$ and $C$) such that
$$\|S(t)b_x\|\leq M,\quad\forall \ t\in[0,t_0].$$

Therefore,

$$\|x\|=\|S(t_x)b_x\|\leq M,\quad\forall \ x\in \bigcup\limits_{0\leq t\leq t_0}S(t) B$$
which shows that the union is bounded.

### Partial answer 2: closedness in the case where $B\subset\mathbb R^n$ (as in the book).

Take $x\in\overline{\bigcup\limits_{0\leq t\leq t_0}S(t) B}$. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\bigcup\limits_{0\leq t\leq t_0}S(t) B$ such that
$$x_n\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} x\tag{1}.$$

For each $n$, there exist $t_n\in[0,t_0]$ and $b_n\in B$ such that $x_n=S(t_n)b_n$. From the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem:

- $(t_n)$ has a subsequence $(t_{n'})$ such that $t_{n'}\overset{n'\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} t^*\in [0,t_0]$.
- $(b_{n'})$ has a subsequence $(b_{n''})$ such that $b_{n''}\overset{n''\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} b^*\in B$.

Then
$$x_{n''}=S(t_{n''})b_{n''}\overset{n''\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} S(t^*)b^*\tag{2}$$
because
$$\|S(t_{n''})b_{n''}-S(t^*)b^*\|\leq \|S(t_{n''})b_{n''}-S(t_{n''})b^*\|+\|S(t_{n''})b^*-S(t^*)b^*\|.$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$x=S(t^*)b^*\in \bigcup\limits_{0\leq t\leq t_0}S(t) B.$$

Comment: Great thanks! I will take this idea and see if I can apply it to the closedness portion.

Comment: Ok, I do have a question. I thought I followed the second Inequality, but 10.2 in the book deals with a difference of solutions at time t with different initial data' you can't necessarily guarantee that you can find an initial condition such that at some time t the solution is identically 0.

Comment: @mathishard.butweloveit Isn't 10.2 valid for $v_0=0$?

Comment: But that doesn't necessarily mean that the solution is $0$ at $t_x$, note that the time is fixed in that inequality.  However, I think if we take $|S(t_x)b_x| \leq |S(t_x)b_x - S(t_x)0| + |S(t_x)0| \leq \delta_{[0,t_0]}(t_0, |b_x|) + |S(t_x)0| \leq \delta_{[0,t_0]}(t_0, |B|) + |S(t_x)0|$, (due to the fact that $\delta$ is nondecreasing) but $S(t_x)(0)$ is bounded above uniformly dependent upon $t_0$ because $S$ is continuous in time.

Comment: @mathishard.butweloveit For each $t\geq 0$, $S(t)$ is a linear operator. Thus $S(t)0=0$ for all $t$. In addition, $t$ is not fixed. The inequality is valid for all $t\in[0,T]$, where $T$ is fixed.

Comment: Then shouldn't I be able to prove that from the definition of linear? I'm only getting that $S(t)(S(0)0) = S(t)0$, but that doesn't seem to give me any information about what $S(t)0$ is.

Comment: @mathishard.butweloveit $S(t)0$ is the value of the linear operator $S(t):H\to H$ at the vector $0\in H$. By linearity, $$S(t)0=S(t)(0-0)=S(t)0-S(t)0=0.$$

Comment: I would believe that if $S$ was linear in space, but I didn't see that in the assumptions?

Comment: @mathishard.butweloveit You are right. I edited the title of my post.

Comment: @mathishard.butweloveit I thought $C^0$ was $C_0$, sory. It seems that the argument in your third comment is correct.

Comment: @mathishard.butweloveit I added a second partial answer for the closedness.

Comment: Yes, I think this is actually a full answer because I noticed the subset was in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so if we assume $B$ is compact we get the more general idea. Thank you so much for the help! I've been meaning to get around to this but it's been a crazy week. It was clever how you avoided using joint continuity by sort of implicitly using the inequality 10.2 for confirming the convergence in (2).